# How to find the position of first instance of duplicates in two equal length, sorted lists

Tags: python, list

I have two random lists of same length, in range of 0 to 99.

```
lista = [12,34,45,56,66,80,89,90]

listb = [13,30,56,59,72,77,80,85]
```

I need to find the first instance of a duplicate number, and in what list it is from.
In this example, I need to find the number '56' in listb, and get the index `i = 2`

Thanks.

Update:
After running it a couple of times, I got this error:

```
    if list_a[i] == list_b[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

like @Asterisk suggested, my two lists are equal length and sorted, both i and j are set to 0 at the beginning. 
that bit is part of a genetic crossover code:

```
  def crossover(r1,r2):
    i=random.randint(1,len(domain)-1) # Indices not at edges of domain
    if set(r1) & set(r2) == set([]): # If lists are different, splice at random
      return r1[0:i]+r2[i:]
    else: # Lists have duplicates
      # Duplicates At Edges
      if r1[0] == r2[0]: # If [0] is double, retain r1
        return r1[:1]+r2[1:]
      if r1[-1] == r2[-1]: # If [-1] is double, retain r2
        return r1[:-1]+r2[-1:]
      # Duplicates In Middle
      else: # Splice at first duplicate point
        i1, i2 = 0, 0
        index = ()
        while i1 < len(r1):
          if r1[i1] == r2[i2]:
            if i1 < i2:
              index = (i1, r1, r2)
            else:
              index = (i2, r2, r1)
            break
          elif r1[i1] < r2[i2]:
            i1 += 1
          else:
            i2 += 1
      # Return A Splice In Relation To What List It Appeared First
      # Eliminates Further Duplicates In Original Lists
      return index[2][:index[0]+1]+index[1][index[0]+1:]
```

The function takes 2 lists and returns one.
domain is a list of 10 tupples: (0,99).

As I said, the error doesn't happen every time, only once in a while.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You say 'random', but your examples are sorted. Which is correct?

Comment: I took it to mean that the lists were randomly generated and then sorted.

Comment: The numbers in the list are generated randomly, in the range of 0 to 99. I have sorted them in advance.
edit: paddy, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lista = [12,34,45,56,66,80,89,90]

listb = [13,30,56,59,72,77,80,85]

i, j = 0, 0
while i < len(lista):    
    if lista[i] == listb[j]:
        if i < j:
            print i, lista
        else:
            print j, listb
        break
    elif lista[i] < listb[j]:
        i += 1
    else:
        j += 1


>>> 
2 [13, 30, 56, 59, 72, 77, 80, 85]
```

Assumptions: both lists have the same length, and they are sorted

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand your comment.

Comment: this code looks like javascript written in python.  A more pythonic way would be to use set() as Blender has done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a python guy, but this is an algorithm question...

You maintain an index into each list and you look at the elements at those two list positions.

Whichever list has the smallest element at the current position, you move to the next element in that list.

When you find an element that is the same as the other list's current element, that is your smallest duplicate.

If you reach the end of either list, there are no duplicates.

Comment: This has the benefit of working with lists of differing lengths.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for all the duplicates, you can use something like this:

```
list_a = [12,34,45,56,66,80,89,90]
list_b = [13,30,56,59,72,77,80,85]

set_a = set(list_a)
set_b = set(list_b)

duplicates = set_a.intersection(set_b)
# or just this:
# duplicates = [n for n in list_a if n in list_b]

for duplicate in duplicates:
    print list_a.index(duplicate)
```

To get the smallest index of a duplicate in either list:

```
a_min = min(map(list_a.index, duplicates))
b_min = min(map(list_b.index, duplicates))

if a_min < b_min:
    print 'a', a_min, list_a[a_min]
else:
    print 'b', b_min, list_b[b_min]
```

If not, this should work a bit better:

```
duplicate = None

for n in set_a:
    if n in set_b:
        duplicate = n
        break

if duplicate is not None:
    print list_a.index(duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just scan all the lists at position 0, then 1, then 2, ... Keep track of what you've seen (you can query a set in O(1) time).

```
def firstDuplicate(*lists):
    seen = {}
    for i,tup in enumerate(zip(*lists)):
        for listNum,value in enumerate(tup):
            position = (listNum,i)
            if value in seen:
                return value, [seen[value], position]
            else:
                seen[value] = position
```

Demo:

```
>>> value,positions = firstDuplicate(lista,listb)
>>> value
56
>>> positions
[(1, 2), (0, 3)]
```

(Does not generalize to N lists... yet. Would need a minor tweak to use a `defaultdict(set)`, insert all indices as a tuple together, then check for duplicates.)